# Detect operating system in Clojure

Tags: configuration, clojure

Is there an equivalent of Common Lisp's `*features`* in Clojure, so you can detect the OS and other environment configuration? Or do I just go through the Java API for that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Probably use the Java API.  It's easy enough, no sense re-inventing the wheel.

```
user> (System/getProperty "os.name")
"Linux"
user> (System/getProperty "os.version")
"2.6.36-ARCH"
user> (System/getProperty "os.arch")
"amd64"
```

Answer (score 6):

To add to Brian Carper's answer, you could easily create a map of system properties via the Java API and bind it to the symbol *features*:

```
(def *features* {
  :name (System/getProperty "os.name"),
  :version (System/getProperty "os.version"),
  :arch (System/getProperty "os.arch")})
```

Which gives you this structure, for example:

```
{:name "Windows 7", :version "6.1", :arch "x86"}
```

Then access a property in any one of the following ways:

```
(:name *features*)
(*features* :name)
(get *features* :name)
```

Whichever floats your boat.

Comment: `System.getProperties` returns a Java Hashtable, so you can also do `(into {} (System/getProperties))` to get a Clojure map of strings to strings and pull the properties out that way.

Comment: @Brian Carper - Nice, shows my lack of real Java use. That said, `System/getProperties` can return a large amount of information, so doing it manually might help someone coming from Lisp who just wants a few properties.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are handling how to get the system info from Java pretty well.  If you want more help interpreting it, here are some examples of how Terracotta did that:

- [VendorVmSignature](http://svn.terracotta.org/svn/tc/dso/trunk/code/base/common/src/com/tc/util/VendorVmSignature.java)
- [VmVersion](http://svn.terracotta.org/svn/tc/dso/trunk/code/base/common-api/src/com/tc/util/runtime/VmVersion.java)
- [Vm](http://svn.terracotta.org/svn/tc/dso/trunk/code/base/common-api/src/com/tc/util/runtime/Vm.java)