# How to inquire Linux machine's informations with Clojure?

Tags: linux, rest, clojure

Well,here is the full demand:Write a simple Clojure programming that can run on a Linux machine that open some RESTful API endpoint(s) for inquiries about the Linux machine's system information (e.g. Memory, Disk, etc.)
  I searched things but there still no clear thought on how or where to begin,regardless of RESTful API,I am trying to write Clojure programing which can gather informations of Linux machine,and maybe it can achieve this function by invoking Java in Clojure?But I don't know much about Java,too.
  Anyway I am trying to find a way.

Comment: PLUS:I am new to Clojure and RESTful API,too

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the best place to ask for a tutorial. If you don't have any specific questions, I suggest you start with something simpler in Clojure to get used to it, then try to tackle this task.

Comment: Start with the understanding that Clojure runs on top of Java so anything you can do in Java (such as querying the environment) you can call from Clojure.

Comment: If you can do it with a Bash command, you can use `clojure.java.shell`'s `sh` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect operating system in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785937/detect-operating-system-in-clojure)

Answer (score 0):

I used `java -XshowSettings:all` to grab a list of all the properties which are set up by the VM, and from that I developed the following:

```
(def system-properties {
  :awt.toolkit                     (System/getProperty "awt.toolkit"),
  :file.encoding                   (System/getProperty "file.encoding"),
  :file.encoding.pkg               (System/getProperty "file.encoding.pkg"),
  :file.separator                  (System/getProperty "file.separator"),
  :java.awt.graphicsenv            (System/getProperty "java.awt.graphicsenv"),
  :java.awt.printerjob             (System/getProperty "java.awt.printerjob"),
  :java.class.path                 (System/getProperty "java.class.path"),
  :java.class.version              (System/getProperty "java.class.version"),
  :java.endorsed.dirs              (System/getProperty "java.endorsed.dirs"),
  :java.ext.dirs                   (System/getProperty "java.ext.dirs"),
  :java.home                       (System/getProperty "java.home"),
  :java.io.tmpdir                  (System/getProperty "java.io.tmpdir"),
  :java.library.path               (System/getProperty "java.library.path"),
  :java.runtime.name               (System/getProperty "java.runtime.name"),
  :java.runtime.version            (System/getProperty "java.runtime.version"),
  :java.specification.name         (System/getProperty "java.specification.name"),
  :java.specification.vendor       (System/getProperty "java.specification.vendor"),
  :java.specification.version      (System/getProperty "java.specification.version"),
  :java.vendor                     (System/getProperty "java.vendor"),
  :java.vendor.url                 (System/getProperty "java.vendor.url"),
  :java.vendor.url.bug             (System/getProperty "java.vendor.url.bug"),
  :java.version                    (System/getProperty "java.version"),
  :java.vm.info                    (System/getProperty "java.vm.info"),
  :java.vm.name                    (System/getProperty "java.vm.name"),
  :java.vm.specification.name      (System/getProperty "java.vm.specification.name"),
  :java.vm.specification.vendor    (System/getProperty "java.vm.specification.vendor"),
  :java.vm.specification.version   (System/getProperty "java.vm.specification.version"),
  :java.vm.vendor                  (System/getProperty "java.vm.vendor"),
  :java.vm.version                 (System/getProperty "java.vm.version"),
  :line.separator                  (System/getProperty "line.separator"),
  :os.arch                         (System/getProperty "os.arch"),
  :os.name                         (System/getProperty "os.name"),
  :os.version                      (System/getProperty "os.version"),
  :path.separator                  (System/getProperty "path.separator"),
  :sun.arch.data.model             (System/getProperty "sun.arch.data.model"),
  :sun.boot.class.path             (System/getProperty "sun.boot.class.path"),
  :sun.boot.library.path           (System/getProperty "sun.boot.library.path"),
  :sun.cpu.endian                  (System/getProperty "sun.cpu.endian"),
  :sun.cpu.isalist                 (System/getProperty "sun.cpu.isalist"),
  :sun.desktop                     (System/getProperty "sun.desktop"),
  :sun.io.unicode.encoding         (System/getProperty "sun.io.unicode.encoding"),
  :sun.java.launcher               (System/getProperty "sun.java.launcher"),
  :sun.jnu.encoding                (System/getProperty "sun.jnu.encoding"),
  :sun.management.compiler         (System/getProperty "sun.management.compiler"),
  :sun.os.patch.level              (System/getProperty "sun.os.patch.level"),
  :sun.stdout.encoding             (System/getProperty "sun.stdout.encoding"),
  :user.country                    (System/getProperty "user.country"),
  :user.dir                        (System/getProperty "user.dir"),
  :user.home                       (System/getProperty "user.home"),
  :user.language                   (System/getProperty "user.language"),
  :user.name                       (System/getProperty "user.name"),
  :user.script                     (System/getProperty "user.script"),
  :user.timezone                   (System/getProperty "user.timezone"),
  :user.variant                    (System/getProperty "user.variant")})
```

Best of luck.

### EDIT

Or, even simpler - calling `(System/getProperties)` returns a map, keyed by property name as a string. On my system I get back

```
{"java.runtime.name" "Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment",
 "sun.boot.library.path" "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_171\\bin", 
 "java.vm.version" "25.171-b11",
 "java.vm.vendor" "Oracle Corporation",
 "java.vendor.url" "http://java.oracle.com/",
 "path.separator" ";",
 "java.vm.name" "Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM",
 "file.encoding.pkg" "sun.io",
 "user.country" "US",
 "user.script" "",
 "sun.java.launcher" "SUN_STANDARD",
 "sun.os.patch.level" "",
 "java.vm.specification.name" "Java Virtual Machine Specification",
 "user.dir" "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32",
 "java.runtime.version" "1.8.0_171-b11",
 "java.awt.graphicsenv" "sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment",
 "java.endorsed.dirs" "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_171\\lib\\endorsed", 
 "os.arch" "amd64", 
 "java.io.tmpdir" "C:\\Users\\whatever\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\",
 "line.separator" "\r\n",
 "java.vm.specification.vendor" "Oracle Corporation",
 "user.variant" "",
 "os.name" "Windows 10",
 "sun.jnu.encoding" "Cp1252",
 "java.library.path" "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_171\\bin;C:\\WINDOWS\\Sun\\Java\\bin;.", 
 "java.specification.name" "Java Platform API Specification",
 "java.class.version" "52.0",
 "sun.management.compiler" "HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers",
 "os.version" "10.0",
 "user.home" "C:\\Users\\whatever",
 "user.timezone" "America/New_York",
 "java.awt.printerjob" "sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob",
 "file.encoding" "Cp1252",
 "java.specification.version" "1.8",
 "java.class.path" "C:\\Users\\...etc...",
 "user.name" "whatever",
 "java.vm.specification.version" "1.8",
 "sun.java.command" "clojure.main",
 "java.home" "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_171",
 "sun.arch.data.model" "64",
 "user.language" "en",
 "java.specification.vendor" "Oracle Corporation",
 "awt.toolkit" "sun.awt.windows.WToolkit",
 "java.vm.info" "mixed mode",
 "java.version" "1.8.0_171",
 "java.ext.dirs" "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_171\\lib\\ext;...etc...", 
 "java.vendor" "Oracle Corporation",
 "file.separator" "\\",
 "java.vendor.url.bug" "http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/", 
 "sun.io.unicode.encoding" "UnicodeLittle",
 "sun.cpu.endian" "little",
 "sun.desktop" "windows",
 "sun.cpu.isalist" "amd64"}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the system's information (CPU and such) on Linux, you can look at the `/proc` filesystem:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" | head -1
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz
```

You can open the file above (and others in the `/proc` filesystem) from any programming language to query the state of the system.